# what is the matlab code to save a textline which is segmented from an image

Tags: image, matlab, save

I have a code for simple line segmentation and I can segment the lines (non-overlapping lines), and I can display the lines using the command. Can anybody tell me how to save the lines as  .jpg? The code segment for segmenting and displaying the line  is shown below

```
for n=1:Ne
   [r,c] = find(L==n);
   n1=imagen(min(r):max(r),min(c):max(c));
   % I want to save this line in this loop with filename.jpg ( in successive
   % numbers like filename_1.jpg, filename_2.jpg and so on ) 
   imshow(~n1);
   %%pause(0.5)
   pause(4)
end
```

I want to save the segmented line in this loop with filename.jpg ( in successive
numbers like filename_1.jpg, filename_2.jpg and so on )
Kindly suggest the command for the same

Answer (score 1):

What i understood is you want to save the images with filename and numbered as `filename_1.jpg` You can write image as

```
str=strcat('filename_',num2str(n),'.jpg')
imwrite(n1,str)
```

Answer (score 1):

imwrite(A,filename,fmt);

A is the image array you want to save, the filename is the output file and 'fmt' is the file format.